# Export specific folders from .tar

Tags: solaris, tar

i have a test.tar in the folder /dir1/dir2/ and i want to extract folders from my test.tar into the directory /dir1/dir2/. The structure of my test.tar ist

```
test.tar
|tdirX/
|tdirY/
|tdirZ/
```

and so on.

now i want to extract the folders tdirX - tdir Y,... to /dir1/dir2/ without extracting test.tar/tdirZ

FYI: I'm running SunOS 5.8

Answer (score 0):

[The `tar(1)` manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tar-1.html) on my Solaris 11.4-beta system states that

> Filename substitution wildcards cannot be used for extracting files from the archive.

... and then suggests to use

```
tar xvf test.tar $( tar tf test.tar | grep '^tdir[XY]' )
```

instead.  This would list the contents of the archive and grep for lines that matched `dir[XY]` at the start of the line.

Actually, it suggests

```
tar xvf test.tar `tar tf test.tar | grep '^tdir[XY]'`
```

but that is the same thing, unless your shell is too ancient to understand `$(...)`.

This feel a bit like a hack (it would break if any of the directories contained a space, for example), and I would in this case probably just use

```
tar xvf test.tar tdirX
tar xvf test.tar tdirY
```

This assumes that the current working directory is `/dir1/dir2` and that the archive is located in that same directory.

Comment: I'd also be concerned with the `$( tar tf test.tar | grep '^tdir[XY]' )` part actually working on Solaris 8 - but I don't have access to Solaris 8 to test.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm assuming you are concerned about the command substitution. If the shell is incapable of understanding `$(...)`, then using the more old fashioned backticked variety would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully follow what you're trying to do.  However, you may find it useful to create a file with the contents of the tarball.  ie:  `tar tf test.tar > /tmp/listing_of_test-tar.txt`.  You could even pipe it through grep or sed before or after file creation to meet your needs.

You could then create a separate file(s) to use the -I for include, or -X exclude options of tar.